# Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: java, android, indexing, cursor, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to code a simple randomizer app. I had the randomizer button working, but then I changed some code (which I thought was irrelevant to the randomizer button) and it started crashing and getting the "CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException Index 0 requested, with a size of 0"  error. I couldn't find any fixes to this that apply to my code. Can anyone help me fix this?

Here is my main class with the button:

```
package com.example.randomgamechooser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);


    }

    public void chooseGame (View view) {
        GameList dbUtil = new GameList(this);
        dbUtil.open();
        String string = dbUtil.getRandomEntry();
        //TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chosenbox);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(string);
        //setContentView (textView);
        dbUtil.close();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }
    //starts the Game Selection activity
    public void openGames (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameSelction.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Here is the GameList class:

```
package com.example.randomgamechooser;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Random;

public class GameList {

    private static final String TAG = "GameList";

    //database name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "game_list";

    //database version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //table name
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "game_list";

    //table columns
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_GENRE = "genre";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    //database creation sql statement
    private static final String CREATE_GAME_TABLE =
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_NAME +" text not null, " + KEY_GENRE + " text not null);";

    //Context
    private final Context mCtx;
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private static SQLiteDatabase mDb;


     //Inner private class. Database Helper class for creating and updating database.

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

         // onCreate method is called for the 1st time when database doesn't exists.
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Creating DataBase: " + CREATE_GAME_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_GAME_TABLE);
        }

         //onUpgrade method is called when database version changes.
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion);
        }
    }

     //Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be opened/created
     //@param ctx the Context within which to work
    public GameList(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

     //This method is used for creating/opening connection
     //@return instance of GameList
     //@throws SQLException
    public GameList open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

     //This method is used for closing the connection.
    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }


     //This method is used to create/insert new game.
     //@param name
     // @param genre
     // @return long
    public long createGame(String name, String genre) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(KEY_GENRE, genre);
        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

     // This method will delete game.
     // @param rowId
     // @return boolean
    public static boolean deleteGame(long rowId) {
        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }


     // This method will return Cursor holding all the games.
     // @return Cursor
    public Cursor fetchAllGames() {
        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
                KEY_GENRE}, null, null, null, null, null);

    }


     // This method will return Cursor holding the specific game.
     // @param id
     // @return Cursor
     // @throws SQLException
    public Cursor fetchGame(long id) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor =
            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_NAME, KEY_GENRE}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        return mCursor;
    }

    public int getAllEntries()
    {
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(
                    "SELECT COUNT(name) FROM game_list", null);
                if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getInt(0);
                }
                return cursor.getInt(0);

    }  

    public String getRandomEntry()
    {

        //id = getAllEntries();
        Random random = new Random();
        int rand = random.nextInt(getAllEntries());
        if(rand == 0)
            ++rand;
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(
                    "SELECT name FROM game_list WHERE _id = " + rand, null);
                if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return cursor.getString(0);
                }
                return cursor.getString(0);

    }


     // This method will update game.
     // @param id
     // @param name
     // @param standard
     // @return boolean
    public boolean updateGame(int id, String name, String standard) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        args.put(KEY_GENRE, standard);
        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

And here is the cause part of the error log:

```
08-01 13:03:38.325: E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
08-01 13:03:38.325: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
08-01 13:03:38.325: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
08-01 13:03:38.325: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
08-01 13:03:38.325: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.example.randomgamechooser.GameList.getRandomEntry(GameList.java:153)
```

EDIT: Here is the ListView class:

```
public class GameSelction extends Activity 
{
    GameList dbUtil = new GameList(this);
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_selction);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            getActionBar() .setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
       displayListView();

        }
    private void displayListView() {
        dbUtil.open();
        Cursor cursor = dbUtil.fetchAllGames();

        // The desired columns to be bound
        String[] columns = new String[] {
          GameList.KEY_NAME,
          GameList.KEY_GENRE,

        };

        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[] { 
          R.id.name,
          R.id.genre,

        };

        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
        //as well as the layout information
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
          this, R.layout.game_info, 
          cursor, 
          columns, 
          to,
          0);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, 
              int position, long rowId) {

            // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
            //Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            GameList.deleteGame(rowId);




            }

        });

       }



    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
        //opens the AddGame activity
    public void openAddgame (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddGame.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
    public void buttonBackMain (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game_selction, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this section of code:

```
public String getRandomEntry()
    {
        //...
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(
                    "SELECT name FROM game_list WHERE _id = " + rand, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return cursor.getString(0);
        }
        return cursor.getString(0);
    }
```

What you ended up doing was saying `return cursor.getString(0);` whether or not there were results in the cursor. So remove the second occurrence, and it should work.

**EDIT:**
After scanning your code, it seems that the only place you use this method is to fill a TextView. In that case you can use this as a chance to communicate a visual error message to yourself or your users, or do anything else with it that you want. So I would suggest using something to the effect of

```
public String getRandomEntry()
    {
         //EDIT: This will make your random generator less biased toward 1.
        Random random = new Random();
        int rand = random.nextInt(getAllEntries()) + 1;
        /* Assuming your _id starts at 1 and auto-increments, this will
         * start the random digits at 1 and go as high as your highest _id */

        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(
                    "SELECT name FROM game_list WHERE _id = " + rand, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return cursor.getString(0);
        }
        return "There were no games in the database to choose from.";
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Try using this. Notice that this code uses `mDb.query()`, which you used elsewhere. I'm not sure why `rawQuery()` would refuse to work, but maybe this will do it.

```
 public String getRandomEntry()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int rand = random.nextInt(getAllEntries()) + 1;

        Cursor cursor = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_NAME}, 
                KEY_ROWID + "=" + rand, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return cursor.getString(0);
        }
        return "There were no games in the database to choose from.";
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. It says that getRandomEntry needs a return statement

Comment: Oh, right. Well, you can't use `return cursor.getString(0)`. I edited in a replacement suggestion.

Comment: In place of your second `return` statement. I'll edit the answer to show you.

Comment: Good news: It compiled. Bad News: "There were no games in the database to choose from." showed up

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I saw your other comment that the ListView shows a list of games. Try using `return Integer.toString(getAllEntries());`. This will print out how many games there are total....But no...`random.nextInt()` would throw an exception if there are 0 games. This means that `getAllEntries()` knows there's at least one game, but your query isn't finding that game. I'll admit, I'm stuck here for the moment. I'll keep looking, but I'm only sure that _something_ went wrong in the query.

Comment: Do you want the ListView class?

Comment: Sure. Maybe we'll be able to find something you did in the ListView that you didn't do here. I've also got another idea. I'll put it in the answer.

Comment: Fixed: I mean that to be `rand` not `id` in the `query()` call.

Comment: That makes it come back with the "There were no games" thing. I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: So your `rawquery()` works just as well as `query()`. I think I'm out of ideas at this point. Try Deactivator2's suggestion of hardcoding an id you know will work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the initial look, the `SQLiteDatabase` object represented by `mDB` appears to be empty, as that's what is throwing the error.

What the error is saying is that your code is requesting the item at index 0 (basically, the first item), but the size of your index is 0 (basically, there are no items in the index).

Somewhere along the line, your database object is either emptied or not populated. To test this, run your `fetchAllGames` method and verify the contents of the index.

Comment: I actually do run the fetchAllGames method in another activity/class that brings up the database as a ListView and it works just fine. Like everything shows up.

Comment: Sorry, everything is pointing to a somehow empty database, or maybe the query is incorrect somehow? Perhaps rand is somehow out of bounds and you're basically getting an empty response back? Could you test it by hardcoding an _id value you know is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't read the whole code, but I guess the problem is that, you are trying to get first element, from empty database. 
Just check if the size of cursor greater than 0, before getting element.

```
if (cursor.getColumnCount() > 0)
return cursor.getString(0); 
else return "no items";
```

Comment: Alright so I can't figure out how to format code to a comment, but I just replaced the code from " if(cursor.moveToFirst()" to the second return statement with what you said. Is that what you mean?